# Dynamic include template angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include, angular-templatecache

So I want to make a directive to automatically include tabs and content, but I am unable to get the content stored in `partials/tabs/tab[x].html`.

`AvailableTabs` - constant defined as an array :

```
myApp.constant("availableTabs", [
    {name:'tab1', title:'One', content:'partials/tabs/tab1.html'},
    {name:'tab2', title:'Two', content:'partials/tabs/tab2.html'},
    {name:'tab3', title:'Three', content:'partials/tabs/tab3.html'}
]);
```

My directive detects the correct tab to be included, and tries to include the tab's content as well:

```
 myApp.directive('myTabs',['availableTabs','$templateCache', function(availableTabs, $templateCache) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: function (elem, attr) {
                for (index = 0; index < availableTabs.length; ++index) {
                    if(availableTabs[index].name == attr.myTabs) {
                        return '<tab heading="'+availableTabs[index].title+'" ng-show="1"> ' +
                                '<div ng-include="'+availableTabs[index].content+'"></div>'+
                            '</tab>';
                       //return '<tab heading="'+availableTabs[index].title+'" ng-show="1"> ' +
                       //    $templateCache.get(availableTabs[index].content)+
                       //    '</tab>';
                    }
                }
            },
    };
}]);
```

The problem is that the content of the tab is empty and I have no errors.

My html is the following:

```
<tabset>
  <div my-tabs="tab1"></div>
  <div my-tabs="tab2"></div>
  <div my-tabs="tab3"></div>
</tabset>
```

I tried injecting `$templateCache` in the directive but it returns `undefined` when retrieving the content, I also tried to take the path relative to the script path but still `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you had missed `'` in `ng-include`, for passing template name as `string`. Because `ng-include` directive requires `string` as input.

```
ng-include="\''+availableTabs[index].content+'\'"
```

will be render as below

```
ng-inlcude="'partials/tabs/tab1.html'"
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Worked like a charm, there was no error and I didn't know where to look. I have to wait 5 min to mark your question :)

Comment: @KA_lin that happens. anyways glad to help you.. Thanks :)